# Time compelixity of for(i=3;i<=n;i=i*2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The time complexity of

```
for(i=3; i<=n; i=i*2)
    x++;
```

is (log (n/3)+1). I'm wondering why?

Comment: No, it's `log(n)` - constants don't count. Apart from that -- think about it. If you keep raising a certain number to higher and higher powers, you will get to the upper bound (`n`) in `ceil(log(n))` steps.

Comment: To demonstrate this (very informally), you can set `n = 3 * 2^(k-1)`, whence `k = log(n/3) + 1`.

Comment: @H2CO3 "They don't count" in big O notation, there's no big O notation here (though you really need to describe what you counting much more accurately to get an exact complexity function)

Comment: @amit "time complexity" is not the same as "number of steps".

Comment: @H2CO3 Agreed, though they are related.

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, they definitely are. (There's the term "asymptotic" in the more precise name for complexity, which I think explains the difference pretty well, at least as a first approximation.)

Comment: @H2CO3 time complexity could be number of comparisons made, which in this case can be counted exactly. Point is, you ignore constants only in big O/Omega/Theta notations, and not for the explicit **exact** complexity function, which could be what the OP is after (but then, as said, more information is needed).

Comment: @amit Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

You will start at `i=3` (given) and iterate until `i>n` (given). For each iteration, the index counter, `i`, doubles (given).

So, the number of iterations will be the number of times you can double a value, for which the initial value is `3` (given).

Therefore, the loop will terminate when `3*2^k>n`. Attempting to solve for the time complexity, k, we reduce the previous calculation to:

```
LET: k,n ∈ Z+ (k,n are positive integers)
==> log(3*2^k)        > log(n)          (given)
==> log(3) + log(2^k) > log(n)          (logarithmic expansion)
==> log(3) + k*log(2) > log(n)          (logarithmic expansion)
==>          k*log(2) ~ log(n)          (removing added constants)
==> k                 ~ log(n) / log(2) (linear operation)
==> k                 ~ log(n - 2)      (logarithmic refactoring)
==> k                 ~ log(n)          (removing added constants)
```

So, the closest complexity for `k` would be `log(n)`, as constants are excluded from general purpose complexity calculations.

If you want the exact number of steps/iterations, from above:

```
LET: k,n ∈ Z+ (k,n are positive integers)
==> log(3*2^k)        ~ log(n)            (given)
==> log(3) + log(2^k) > log(n)            (logarithmic expansion)
==> log(3) + k*log(2) > log(n)            (logarithmic expansion)
==> k*log(2)          > log(n) - log(3)   (linear refactoring)
==> k*log(2)          > log(n/3)          (logarithmic refactoring)
==> k                 > log(n/3) / log(2) (linear refactoring)
```

The `+1` basically is being used to round-up the number of operations as k is unlikely to be an integer, so we need at least `ceiling(k)` operations to complete. So the exact number of steps becomes `(log(n/3)+1)/log(2)`.

Is there an explanation for why the `log(2)` is left out of your solution? If you're looking for the specific number of iterations as opposed to the general case (ie: big-oh notation)?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last page of [these slides](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt).

It is specifically:

[image]